# Paintcode export to subfolder

Tags: paintcode

When defining export to image settings for a canvas, is there a way to let PaintCode export to different folders depending on the canvas?

A few of my canvasses are language dependend and need to be exported into subfolders with the language in it (android)....

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option for doing what you want.

I believe what you should be doing, instead, is to parameterize the String itself, like so:

[image: localizable]

This way you expose your `String` and can set whatever you want at runtime.

Comment: This would work if the language dependancy is text only. However in my case its not, I have completely different artwork (logo) for each language.

Comment: I see... I think the only solution in this case would be to have separate PaintCode projects (instead of many Canvases in the same file). Then you could export each one into different folders. But that sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: And not ideal I want to keep the overview by using one paintcode file. I therefore will write a script that after export moves the files into the correct folders.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. And you could write the script in Swift. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can name each canvas with / to get subfolders. E.g. a canvas named

```
Resources/Images/Top
```

will export into [root]Resources/Images/Top.png

You can even put / in the "File Suffix" field to get even further into subfolders.

For example when I export png's into an iOS imageset I name each canvas like this:

```
Canvas name: Assets.xcassets/TopLeft0.imageset/
File Suffix: Image
File Suffix: Image@2X
File Suffix: Image@3X
```